# What is the meaning of the folder names in Winsxs folder (windows run time assemblies directory)

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, winsxs

**Background:**

- Windows shared run-time libraries located at `C:\windows\Winsxs` folder
- Inside Winsxs, there are two important sub folders also located as `policies` and `Manifests`
- Other than that, there are plenty of run-time assemblies located in side each other sub folders.
- All the sub-folders inside `Winsxs` and  `policies`  having same naming format.

**Eg Folder Names:**

- Run times: `x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_x-ww_6f74963e`
- Policies: `x86_policy.9.0.Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_x-ww_b7353f75`

As I know first part of the name (x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1) describe "processorArchitecture"(`x86`) , "Name" (`Microsoft.VC90.CRT`), "publicKeyToken" (`1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b`) and "Version"(`9.0.30729.1`) of the assembly or policy.

**Question:** 
What is the last part of the assembly(`x-ww_6f74963e`) or policy(`x-ww_b7353f75`) folder name describes?

---

Ok here is the original issue (but quite long story). I deployed my C++ MFC application in windows XP computer that previously installed some of C++ redistribute packages and some security patches of run-time assemblies. So these pre-installed C++ redistribute packages automatically deployed some run-time policies in `Winsxs/policies`. those policies  force to use new run-time assemblies instead of the one uses and deployed by my application. But some times these newer DLLs not there because of some other application removal or assemblies can be corrupted. So I'm finding a way to deploy run time assemblies specifically use for my application (it means my app must use the once deployed by it and ignore the policies). So I think this last part of the sub directory name associate with the identity of application. I need to find it.

Comment: First of all, tag abuse...and I'm pretty sure MSDN is where you can figure it out.

Comment: What do you mean by 'tag abuse'? any irrelevant tag there?

Comment: What is the practical application of this question?  I would have thought the folder names were an implementation detail whose significance is irrelevant to anyone outside of Microsoft.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question, so the C++ and visual-C++ tags don't apply.  And it may not even be an appropriate question for StackOverflow.

Comment: @HarryJohnston/ Richard Schwartz: Please look at the edited last part of the question. thank for the guidence

Comment: And I found this post, but it doesn't explain what is the meaning of last part. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonwis/archive/2005/12/28/507863.aspx

Comment: I don't understand why you need to know the names of the folders. The whole point of side-by-side deployment is that it solves the problem you describe with different programs using different versions of the DLLs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're trying to solve your problem the wrong way.  But first, what exactly is your problem?  Is your application failing to start because it can't find the DLLs?  If an assembly is corrupted, that's a sysadmin problem, not your problem, and it should be resolvable by uninstalling and reinstalling the relevant program(s).  If the assembly you installed isn't being found because another application was uninstalled, that's another story altogether.

Comment: It is explained well in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonwis/archive/2005/12/28/507863.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't trust global cache (and on WinXP it is super easy to corrupt it), you might have to install private copies of assemblies and override them in your application config.

Here is a hack I am using to override some assemblies for debugging purposes:

In your exe folder, drop the file named yourexename.exe.config with policy information redirecting real assembly version to something that will never exist in global cache. For example:

```
<configuration>
    <windows>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="someassemblyname" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="sometoken"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.0.999.998" newVersion="1.0.999.999"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </windows>
</configuration>
```

Take contents of the assembly that you want to use, drop it into the same folder and edit manifest to have the version you used above. For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <noInheritable></noInheritable>
    <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="someassemblyname" version="1.0.999.999" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="sometoken"></assemblyIdentity>
    <file name="somedll.dll"/>
</assembly>
```

In the end you will get following files in your install folder:

```
yourexename.exe
yourexename.exe.config
somedll.dll
someassemblyname.manifest
```

And your executable will pick up private copy of the dll.

More info here: [Application Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

EDIT: if you have problems like "the application failed to initialize properly" or "side by side configuration is incorrect" (and you **will** have them once you start playing with sxs), use **[sxstrace](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875651%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)** tool for diagnostics (not available on Windows XP though). That will tell you exactly which assembly causes problems.

Comment: Actually your answer open me a whole new direction and rally thank you for the new idea. But one more question, My application note only include one `exe`, it also include some other DLLs as well. those DLLs also uses same run-time assemblies. So when I change the `someassemblyname.manifest` files version. I seems to affect other DLLs. because program shows same error. please assist

Comment: the error shows by the application is `The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0150002). Click on OK to terminate the application`

Comment: In this articles first comment I got answer for my DLL issue. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. @Eugene: you are a guy should be in Microsoft. =)